# First Order Stochastic Dominance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I am reading up on stochastic dominance(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance) and have some questions:

PDF and CDF of Gamble A and B look like this.

[image]

Since the CDF of A is always less than or equal to CDF of B, A is preferred to B by first order stochastic dominance.

My question is :

Since $P[A\ge x] \ge P[B \ge x] $ or $P[A\ge x] \gt P[B \ge x] $ for all x by first order stochastic dominance, shouldn't the probability of A for each percentage be higher or equal to the probability of B for each percentage?

Am i right? Need some clarification on this...

Answer (score 2):

If $P[A\ge x] \ge P[B \ge x] $ for all $x$ then $P[A\le x] \le P[B \le x] $ for all $x$. 
And the CDF of $X$ is $F_X:x\mapsto P[X\le x]$, not $x\mapsto P[X\ge x]$.